# Bindings for WCF Service running in a local network

Tags: windows-services, wcf-data-services, wcf-binding, nettcpbinding, basichttpbinding

My scenario is that i have hosted a WCF Service in a windows service. This WCF service will be used within a local network. Client application will pass on a simple data value to the WCFService. No big amount of datas involved.
What is best binding to be used in this situation? And Why.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend 'netTcpBinding' .it's faster than HTTP based bindings because it encodes the messages in a binary instead of text format,and it supports all the features like sessions, streaming etc..also it supports duplex contracts and transactions.